# Can php+mysql scale to handle 5000 request per second?

Tags: mysql, php, traffic, load-testing

I have web application build with php and mysql, and I except 5000 requests/sec in the first 6 months. and I register a dedicated server with `CPU intel Xeon 4 cores 3.3GHz, 16G ram, Uplink 1000Mbps, bandwidth 25TB`, and I tested the webserver using ab benchwork and the results is:

```
for txt file : ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://mywebsite.com/file.txt
results: 1500 requests/second
for php file with only echo "test";
results: 130 requests/second
```

I just want to know where is the bottleneck?.